# Is there a better way to update user view instead of refreshing?

Tags: javascript, php

In the database I have something like Line, Word and Character. That is, a Word must belong to a specific Line, the same goes for Character (or you can think of a multi-level menu, each menu item can be another menu). I'm writing a management page to interact with the database. Each time the user insert/delete a record, the page must be refreshed to show the changes. However, this approach is too annoying for my users (although the refresh is automatic). **Is it possible to show the changes without refreshing the whole page? If it is, how?** Thank you.

UPDATE: The data is shown as multi-level list (the picture below is an example) and can be collapsed/expanded. When I refresh the page, they are all collapsed (which annoys my users).

[image]

Comment: It is possible and to do so you would need to use AJAX

Comment: Take care: by doing so, you'll end up handling the whole navigation thing while a simple refresh leave it to the browser (history, fav, cache, and so on are better handled by browser than by website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using AJAX(Asynchronous JavaScript And XML). You can update a web page without reloading it using ajax. You can use jQuery ajax() which is so simple to integrate. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Here is an example-

```
  $.ajax({
       method: "get",
       url: "/action.php",
       data: {item_id: item_id, vote: vote},
       dataType: "html"
    })
    .done(function(msg){
       // Update view of the web page, it could be deleting or updating a div
    })
    .fail(function(msg){
      alert(msg);
    });

/*
method - get/post
url - which will handle your request
data - data you want to send to server
dataType - response type, html/json/text etc
*/
```

If it works without any problem then the `done` method will trigger otherwise `fail` method will trigger.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying something like a live suggestions display while you type on the search bar.  The  ajax. If you just want to show the newly updated record on the be view page, a redirect would do